# How to display characters of apple script popup in Asterisk

Tags: macos, applescript

i was written apple script for popup which is taking input as a plain text but i want i don't want to display that plain text i require it should be display in Asterisk sign (like dot, star etc).
can some body help me to do it.

**Following is code:**

```
tell application "Finder"
    set system_pwd to text returned of (display dialog "Enter System Password ?" 
with title "Password" buttons {"Ok", "Cancel"} 
 default answer "" default button "Ok")
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `hidden answer`is your friend. You can find such parameters inside the User Interaction section from the StandardAdditions dictionary. BTW you don't need to tell the Finder for displaying a dialog.

```
set system_pwd to text returned of (display dialog "Enter System Password ?" with title "Password" buttons {"Ok", "Cancel"} default answer "" default button "Ok" with hidden answer)
```

Please think about security and don't store the variable system_pwd in a text file or other persistent property.

Enjoy,
Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thank you so much  @ShooTerko, it exactly same that i require and and thanks for the info i will work on it

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
system_pwd=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Password: " default answer "" with hidden answer)')
```

Again, be careful with what you do with the system_pwd variable!